# Alternate way to access multiple columns independently from a database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

My application stores three items: "name", "email", "mobile" in its database under the same table. I want to access each of them independently so that I could display their value under their respective TEXTVIEWs. I access them independently because if I access them all through one single function I won't be able to display the values

Currently, I have to write a function for each column so as to get information from it.

Example to get "email"

```
public String getUserEmail(String mobile) {

        String[] columns = new String[] {USER_EMAIL};
        Cursor c = MainDataBase.query(REG_INFO_TABLE, columns, USER_MOBILE_NUMBER + "=" + mobile, null, null, null, null);

        String result = "";

        int email = c.getColumnIndex(USER_EMAIL);



        while(c.moveToNext()) {

            result = result + c.getString(email);

        }
        return result;

    }
```

So, if I need the the "name", I'll have to write another function similar to above to get it.

Now, if I need to access 50 such columns, I'll have to make 50 such functions which does not sound good. Is there any other way I can do this? Can arrays be used here?

Comment: Hmm...50 columns in a table sounds like you might need to rethink your database design. Can some of these columns be normalized into other tables?

Comment: @MonadNewb 50 columns is just an example. My my current case I have 13 columns in a particular table. These columns store details like facebook profile link, website, phone number, linkedin profile etc. So, there is not much scope for normalizing, is there?
I needed the values under those 13 columns independently so that I could use them for `setText` in `TextView`.
I went for the "array based solution" over creating 13 separate function for each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider creating a `User` class that holds the data for each `User`. Then you change `getAllRegInfo()` to return a `User` object. This has the advantage that the rest of your app only accesses `User`s and has no idea where the data comes from. It is also much more expressive to write

```
User user = getAllRegInfo();
String name = user.getName();
```

rather than

```
String[] user = getAllRegInfo();
String name = user[0];
```

In addition, a `User` class can have fields of any type rather than being forced to convert all data to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found an alternative. It is using arrays only.

Here is the code:

```
public String[] getAllRegInfo() {

        String[] columns = new String[] {USER_NAME, USER_EMAIL, USER_MOBILE_NUMBER};
        Cursor c = MainDataBase.query(REG_INFO_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

        String[] result = new String[3];

        for(int j=0; j<3; j++) {

            result[j] = "";

        }

        int[] column = new int[3];

        column[0] = c.getColumnIndex(USER_NAME);
        column[1] = c.getColumnIndex(USER_EMAIL);
        column[2] = c.getColumnIndex(USER_MOBILE_NUMBER);

        while(c.moveToNext()) {

            for(int i = 0; i<3; ++i) {

                result[i] = c.getString(column[i]);

            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```

Of course, one will have to manually asign the array indexes to the columns. Like this:

```
            column[0] = c.getColumnIndex(USER_NAME);
            column[1] = c.getColumnIndex(USER_EMAIL);
            column[2] = c.getColumnIndex(USER_MOBILE_NUMBER);
```

The solution seems to be working fine but I'm not sure how scalable it is.

Comment: The first for loop is unnecessary since the for loop inside the while loop at the end initializes the `String`s in `result`.

Comment: Actually, in my particular case `""` was needed because I use it to check for a particular condition. Otherwise, yes, the first for loop is not required.

Comment: What condition? In the code you posted here, I don't see that condition. Or do you mean that there is other code that checks if a given column is empty? If so, using the default `null` value in each element of the array is probably be better since it is possible that the database contains empty Strings.

Comment: @MonadNewb yes it is in another part of the code. You are correct, checking for null will be better.

Comment: When you create an array of references, the elements are initialized to `null`. Most likely you should use this default value for your condition check rather than an empty string.